# Cannot scale gif move frame in Android Canvas

Tags: android, scale, android-canvas, gif

I have problem with scaling GIF movie frame. I'm using Canvas.scale(float sx, float sy) before drawing the frame. But it doesn't draw scaled frame, it draws nothing. Any ides ?

Comment: You should draw draw gif first, then scale canvas.

Answer (score 3):

If your trying to make a dedicated View that is scale-able and reusable within another layout you should use the View's getWidth() and getHeight() methods as well.

I ran into this issue when changing the View's dedicated size: canvas.getWidth() is the width of the entire screen and not the views width so I modified the onDraw method as follows.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();  

    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setAntiAlias(true);

    if (cur == 0) cur = now;  

    if(movie != null)
    {
        float scale = 1f;
        if(movie.height() > getHeight() || movie.width() > getWidth())
            scale = ( 1f / Math.min(canvas.getHeight() / movie.height(), canvas.getWidth() / movie.width()) ) + 0.25f;
        else    
            scale = Math.min(canvas.getHeight() / movie.height(), canvas.getWidth() / movie.width());

        canvas.scale(scale, scale);
        canvas.translate(((float)getWidth() / scale - (float)movie.width())/2f,
                ((float)getHeight() / scale - (float)movie.height())/2f);

        int relTime = (int)((now - cur) % movie.duration());
        movie.setTime(relTime);
        movie.draw(canvas, 0, 0);


        invalidate();
    }
}
```

Notice the getWidth(), getHeight() if statement checking to see if the movie is larger than the view, in my case my views height was 160 but my GIF was 260, however using the other method it would always draw the GIF too big, with these changes I was able to test and see it working in both cases where my View was 1280 X 900 and the image scaled up and also where my view was 1000 X 160 and it scaled down.

Best of luck, and have fun :D

-Chris

Comment: I found that only using the 'else' statement in the drawing code yielded better results - ie. it scaled to ALL devices. I nixed the 'if' statement in my project.

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    canvas.scale(0.5f, 0.5f); // scale gif to its half size

    super.onDraw(canvas);

    /* movie.setTime . . . */

    movie.draw(canvas, ...);

    this.invalidate();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This was my solution:

```
public class GifImageView extends View {
    private InputStream mInputStream;
    private Movie mMovie;
    public int mWidth, mHeight;
    private long mStart;
    private Context mContext;

    public GifImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public GifImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public GifImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        this.mContext = context;
        if (attrs.getAttributeName(1).equals("background")) {
            int id = Integer.parseInt(attrs.getAttributeValue(1).substring(1));
            setGifImageResource(id);
        }
    }

    private void init() {
        setFocusable(true);
        mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(mInputStream);
        mWidth = mMovie.width();
        mHeight = mMovie.height();

        requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        setMeasuredDimension(mWidth, mHeight);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

        if (mStart == 0) {
            mStart = now;
        }

        if (mMovie != null) {
            int duration = mMovie.duration();
            if (duration == 0) {
                duration = 1000;
            }

            float scale = Math.min((float) canvas.getHeight() / (float) mMovie.height(), (float) canvas.getWidth() / (float) mMovie.width());

            canvas.scale(scale, scale);
            canvas.translate(((float) mWidth / scale - (float) mMovie.width()) / 2f,
                ((float) mHeight / scale - (float) mMovie.height()) / 2f);

            int relTime = (int) ((now - mStart) % duration);

            mMovie.setTime(relTime);
            mMovie.draw(canvas, 0, 0);
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    public void setGifImageResource(int id) {
        mInputStream = mContext.getResources().openRawResource(id);
        init();
    }

    public void setGifImageUri(Uri uri) {
        try {
            mInputStream = mContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            init();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("GIfImageView", "File not found");
        }
    }

    public void setSize(int dimension) {
        mWidth = dimension;
        mHeight = dimension;
    }
}
```

add it to your layout-file:

```
<GifImageView
        android:id="@+id/gifView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/image" />
```

then you can simply set the dimension in your Java code:

```
gifView.setSize(dimension);
```

Answer (score 0):

This sample allows us to resize **GIF** and **fit in to the screen accordingly** to the original size of image.

[image]

***PlayGifView.class***

```
public class PlayGifView extends View{

    private static final int DEFAULT_MOVIEW_DURATION = 1000;

    private int mMovieResourceId;
    private Movie mMovie;

    private long mMovieStart = 0;
    private int mCurrentAnimationTime = 0;
public Context context;
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public PlayGifView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
       /**
        * Starting from HONEYCOMB have to turn off HardWare acceleration to draw
        * Movie on Canvas.
        */
       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
           setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
       }

   }

    public void setImageResource(int mvId){
        this.mMovieResourceId = mvId;
       mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(getResources().openRawResource(mMovieResourceId));
       requestLayout();
    }

    public void setMovieData(Movie movieImg){
        mMovie = movieImg;
        requestLayout();
    }

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
   if(mMovie != null){

       //Find higest
       int exceptedSize = 200;
       int highest = 0;
       int quality = 0;
       if(mMovie.height()>mMovie.width()){
           highest=mMovie.height();
       }else{
           highest=mMovie.width();
       }

       //Get Display Size
       Display display = ((Activity) getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
       Point size = new Point();
       display.getSize(size);

       setMeasuredDimension((int)(((float)mMovie.width()/(float)highest)*((float) size.x))
               , (int)(((float)mMovie.height()/(float)highest)*((float)size.x)));
   }else{
       setMeasuredDimension(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), getSuggestedMinimumHeight());
   }
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
   if (mMovie != null){
       updateAnimtionTime();

       //Get Display Size
       Display display = ((Activity) getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
       Point size = new Point();
       display.getSize(size);

       float scale = Math.max((float) canvas.getHeight() / (float) mMovie.height(), (float) canvas.getWidth() / (float) mMovie.width());

       canvas.scale(scale, scale);
       canvas.translate(((float) size.x / scale - (float) mMovie.width()) / 2f,
               0);

       drawGif(canvas);
       invalidate();
   }else{
//       drawGif(canvas);
   }
}

private void updateAnimtionTime() {
   long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

   if (mMovieStart == 0) {
       mMovieStart = now;
   }
   int dur = mMovie.duration();
   if (dur == 0) {
       dur = DEFAULT_MOVIEW_DURATION;
   }
   mCurrentAnimationTime = (int) ((now - mMovieStart) % dur);
}

private void drawGif(Canvas canvas) {
   mMovie.setTime(mCurrentAnimationTime);
   mMovie.draw(canvas, 0, 0);
   canvas.restore();
}

}
```

***Main Activity.class***

```
PlayGifView pGif = findViewById(R.id.viewGif);
pGif.setImageResource(R.drawable.ads1);
```

***activity_main.xml***

```
<com.---- Yours-----.PlayGifView
    android:id="@+id/viewGif"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```